# Desperately looking for Ubuntu14.04 ISO file

Tags: 14.04

I have been looking to download Ubuntu 14.04 ISO image file for hours but all what I can find is either 14.04.**2** or 14.04.**1** releases.

Could any one give me the links I need ?

Why do I want this precise release? Because other versions will end soon according to this [page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Comment: When .2 dies you will already have .3

Comment: @Rinzwind yes but to upgrade I will have to save the data first and so on,  but for a lazy one like me I do not like that

Comment: Your reasoning is not correct: you always need to make backups regardless of upgrades.

Comment: @begueradj you will not have to reinstall for the new update. It will be a normal update. All installing 14.04.0 will do is waste your time as you have to install 300MB of updates. Then your computer will be 14.04.2 anyway - like mine is. `lsb_release -a` shows `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS` - even though I installed 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the old versions of 14.04 from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.0/

Or just click on your suitable link here:

- [Desktop 64 bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.0/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso)
- [Desktop 32 bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.0/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso)

---

Edit:

What Tim is saying is just completely true, it's just an update so you don't have to care of reinstalling. It's just a bunch of updates and bug fixes , and once you install 14.04 and start updating you'r moving to 14.04.2 and 14.04.3 smoothly if we are going to be up to date, so it doesn't matter to just install 14.04.3 and save some time and updates .

Comment: @begueradj they link to both. Also you won't have to upgrade, it will do it automatically.

Comment: @begueradj you are welcome

Comment: @begueradj Please see my answer, *you will not need to reinstall for 14.04.3*. All installing 14.04.0 will do is waste your time as you have to install lots of updates.

Answer (score 0):

14.04.2 will not "die" soon. Well it will, but you will have updated to 14.04.3 by then. By updated, I just mean you will see the update manager

You will not have to reinstall or anything, it will be automatic. No trouble.

Also, all installing 14.04 will do is mean you get 300+ MB of updates. Then it will "turn into" 14.04.2.

Save the time, and install 14.04.2 straight away.

---

You may also be a little confused about the LTS nature of Ubuntu 14.04. It simply means there will be updates for 5 years, and that will include new "point releases". Your computer automatically gets these updates.

Comment: thank you for the explanation and details but then I do not understand why on the link they gave there is a difference between 14.04 and 14.04.2 releases since using the first one, as you said, leads to using the second one

Comment: @begueradj it means that the updates are already included in the download, you don't have to download lots more files.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but what I do not understand is that aparently there is no way to use 14.04 release since all updates will lead to 14.04.2 ?

Comment: @begueradj that is right - but you will still have all your programs and files. Why do you need to use 14.04.0? It's an old version of 14.04... 14.04.3 will be out before 14.04.2 goes away.

Comment: thank you, but just by curiosity i do not see 14.04.3 on internet

Comment: @begueradj 14.04.3 is not released yet. 14.04.2 is still current and alive.